# What is the story of Vishwakarma creating the Saunanda mace used by Balrama?

Tags: asuras, weapon, balarama, vishwakarma, markandeya-purana

The **[Markandeya Puran](http://hinduonline.co/Scriptures/Puranas/MarkandeyaPurana.html)** Section 1.11.5 mentions the following story:

> There lives a highly powerful and fierce Danava in Rasatala. He makes the earth yawn and therefore he is called Kujrimbha. Whatever wonder is there on earth or in heaven that is his work. How is it that you do not know him? **That vicious-minded one stole away the mace Sunanda which was formerly made by the celestial Architect.** He kills his enemies in battle with it. Living in Patala he rives the earth with it and accordingly creates a door for all the Asuras. Now he has riven the earth with that mace Sunanda. How will you enjoy this earth without having killed him? **This dreadful and powerful (demon) spoils sacrifices, distresses the gods and welcomes the demons.** He has this mace for his weapon. If you can slay that enemy living at the furtherest end of Patala then will you be the lord of the entire earth and the great god. **The mace of that powerful one is spoken of by people as Sounanda; O king, intelligent men call it Balavala.** O king, **when touched by a female that mace grows powerless.** On the second day it again grows powerful.

Furthermore the text states:

> **After the death of Kujrimbha, the king of the serpents, Ananta, designated Sesha, took up that mace.**

So presumably, this was the mace used by Sheshnaga in his incarnation of Balrama? I want to know if there is some back story to the construction of the mace given in any other scripture - **Was it actually created by Vishwakarma & if so how and when did the demon steal it?**

Comment: I can confirm that both the Vishnu Purana and the Harivamsa call Balarama's Gada as Saunanda.

Comment: Awesome so that tells us we're n the right track. Do any of those  mention the story of why and how the Gada was created?